# remove '-' in front of some returned lines in query results

Tags: postgresql

`COALESCE( dim_Study_Type.classical_intelerad_study_description, '' ) AS Classical_Intelerad_Study_Description,`

Here is some of the results I get:

```
-CT HEAD WO
CHEST SINGLE VIEW
-XR CHEST
CT ANGIOGRAPHY 
-CTA HEAD
```

How do I trim or remove the '-' when they exist?

Comment: Have a look at `replace(<string>,<matching_string>,<replace_with>)`. _(Not that you could have searched that by your self)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the starting char, you can use [`ltrim`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

`select ltrim(COALESCE( dim_Study_Type.classical_intelerad_study_description, '' ),'-')`

ex:

```sql
select ltrim('-ab-cd-', '-');
 ltrim
--------
 ab-cd-
(1 row)
```